# Using 2 OpenNI devices

Tags: openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone used 2 Microsoft Kinect or 2 ASUS Xtion ? How can one do so ? Does ROS allow for 2 OpenNI devices with the same roscore ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57259/using-2-openni-devices/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Openni and ROS do support multiple RGBD cameras. The first thing you need to do is make sure you have adequate hardware support. RGBD cameras transmit a lot of data via USB, going beyond what one bus can handle. Thus, you need to make sure that you have two separate USB2.0 buses/hubs available. (For Linux, the command 'lsusb' provides this information.)  Once you do that, you can easily just call openni_launch multiple times, like so:

```
<!-- Entry point for using multiple RGBD devices -->
<launch>
  <param name="use_sim_time" value="false" />
  <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch">
    <arg name="camera" value="camera1" />
    <arg name="device_id" value="#1" />
    <arg name="depth_registration" value="true" />
  </include>

  <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch">
    <arg name="camera" value="camera2" />
    <arg name="device_id" value="#2" />
    <arg name="depth_registration" value="true" />
  </include>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [stantol](https://answers.ros.org/users/2884/stantol/) with karma: 146 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4